# Custom UICollectionViewFlowLayout Borders

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, swift2, ios9, uicollectionviewlayout

I created a Swift class that inherits from UICollectionViewFlowLayout and i've been able to successfully do some neat stuff like change the spacing between each box that it draws. I'm drawing a calendar so just imagine 28-31 boxes, 7 per row, depending on the month.

..one thing I never figured out was how to do something like make the right border blank vs. not. Or the top border. I recently changed the spacing to 0 between each box, and now the boxes' borders overlap.

I'd love to programmatically make all the right borders blank so the left border of it's next one acts as the mutual border (so it's not a double border). Then, on the last box in the collection for each row, I can make that have a right border. Know what I'm saying? Nice clean thin border around each box.

Do I do this in my   override func layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]?  Perhaps somewhere else?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

BANG! I figured it out. This is so cool, because now I can programmatically decide when to add the borders below (i.e. if x then day.layer.addSublayer(topBorder), otherwise don't add it)

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView!, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UICollectionViewCell!
    {
        let day = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CalendarDayCollectionViewCell

        /* adds a border to entire grid */
        day.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor().CGColor
        //day.layer.borderWidth = 1  //can also do .cornerRadius to round out borders



        //top border
        let topBorder = CALayer()
        topBorder.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, day.frame.size.width, 1.0);
        topBorder.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.8, alpha: 1.0).CGColor


        // bottom border
        let bottomBorder = CALayer()
        bottomBorder.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, day.frame.size.height-1, day.frame.size.width, 1.0);
        bottomBorder.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.8, alpha: 1.0).CGColor

        let leftBorder = CALayer()
        leftBorder.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, day.frame.size.height);
        leftBorder.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.8, alpha: 1.0).CGColor

        let rightBorder = CALayer()
        rightBorder.frame = CGRectMake(day.frame.size.width - 1, 0.0, 1.0, day.frame.size.height);
        rightBorder.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.8, alpha: 1.0).CGColor

        day.layer.addSublayer(topBorder)
        day.layer.addSublayer(bottomBorder)
        day.layer.addSublayer(leftBorder)
        day.layer.addSublayer(rightBorder)

return day
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot really explicitly remove one side or two sides of a border, not support by `CALayer`.

But based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19796230/2710486), you should be able to achieve by overlapping the cells, so you're correct that you should override `func layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect: CGRect)`

BTW, I think you can have a try with

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    let borderWidth = 5
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(-borderWidth,-borderWidth,-borderWidth,-borderWidth);
}
```

Comment: interesting, ok thanks - what about only drawing one side vs. another? Or doing something in  func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView!, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UICollectionViewCell!
   ?

Comment: As I said, `CALayer` does not support *special* border, although you can draw one side of border by hacking. However, if you really want to try this. In `cellForItemAtIndexPath ,` my suggestion is that you could try to add four custom subviews, sitting at four sides, pretended to be borders. And set their `width`/`height` corresponds to `indexPath`%7